# Server boot fail: ext4_da_writepages: jbd2_start

Tags: linux, debian

We have a server running Debian Linux and syddenly it cannot boot, keeps displaying errors like the following:

```
EXT4-fx (ploop51580p1):ext4_da_writepages: jbd2_start: 8192 pages, ino 993082; err -30
```

Server has a vm running on it. We cannot have ssh access neither to the server nor to the vm, getting the following error, after entering our credentials.

```
-bash: /etc/profile: Input/output error
-bash: /home/.../.profile: Input/output error
Connection to .... closed.
```

Server asks for credentials which means that some services have started.

We've tried to restart the server multiple times without any advance. Server has 2 hdd disks raid.

The problem is that the console does not allow us to enter any commands and keeps displaying the error messages.

What could we do and how could we get more information on what is wrong? Does it appear to be a hard disk failure problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `EXT4-fx (ploop51580p1):ext4_da_writepages: jbd2_start: 8192 pages, ino 993082; err -30` the first error? What is it first saying about the other drives?

Comment: the first one says end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 46416176